# How to remove the space between navbar logo and navbar menu and navbar logo behind the text

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm stuck with this. I want to remove the space between navbar brand and navbar menu. Also when i put navbar logo image, the navbar-fixed will grow bigger and it will cover my page header.

```
       <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">



                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <span class="logo"><img width="40%" src="images/windsor-logo_horizontal-colored.png" alt="WindSor"></span>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"> Home</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5C8R.png)

the circle space is what i want to remove.

here is my CSS :

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

@media(min-width:767px) {
    .navbar {
        padding: 20px 0;
        -webkit-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
        transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
        margin: 
    }

    .top-nav-collapse {
        padding: 0;
    }
}



.intro-section {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #fff;
}

.about-section {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #eee;
}

.services-section {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #fff;
}

.contact-section {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #eee;
}
```

Comment: Give us your css code.

Comment: i did not put fixed it is in the navbar

Comment: sir i gave my css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably add the class `.navbar-brand` to the

```
<span class="logo"><img width="40%" src="images/windsor-logo_horizontal-colored.png" alt="WindSor"></span>
```

check the jsFiddle : https://plnkr.co/edit/uquYGOtMFu2cNbbwQQFT?p=preview

Comment: sir it works good in desktop but when i tried it in mobile the image will lapse the navbar menu

Comment: how can i fixed it in mobile sir ?

Comment: Can you please attach a screenshot of mobile layout!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are facing the problem with your stylesheet. Using only bootstrap everything is working fine. View the fiddle in full page. you will find the correct output.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">



                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <span class="logo"><img width="40%" src="https://assets.servedby-buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/28536" alt="WindSor"></span>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"> Home</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
```

Comment: i want to remove the circle that i've put in screenshot

Comment: how can  fixed it in mobile sir ?